# How can I rename the default index created by a one-to-one relation in typeorm?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

Typeorm creates by default a UNIQUE INDEX with name REL_ + something to a one-to-one relation in migration. I want to rename that index.

My entity is shown below:

```
export const CompanySettingsEntity = new EntitySchema<ICompanySettingsEntity>({
    name: 'companySettings',
    tableName: 'companySettings',
    columns: {
        idCompanySettings: {
            type: 'smallint',
            primary: true,
            generated: true,
            unsigned: true,
            comment: 'Chave primária',
        },
        idCompany: {
            type: 'smallint',
            unsigned: true,
            comment: 'Chave da Empresa',
        },
        radarCulturalImage: {
            type: 'varchar',
            length: 100,
            collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            charset: 'utf8mb4',
            nullable: true,
            default: () => 'NULL',
            comment: 'Imagem customizada da empresa usada no radar',
        },
        disableCountry: {
            type: 'enum',
            enum: ['true', 'false'],
            default: 'false',
            comment: 'Desabilita o país',
        },
        disablePositionLevel: {
            type: 'enum',
            enum: ['true', 'false'],
            default: 'false',
            comment: 'Desabilita nível de cargo',
        },
        disableSchoolLevel: {
            type: 'enum',
            enum: ['true', 'false'],
            default: 'false',
            comment: 'Desabilita nível escolar',
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: 'timestamp',
            default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
            nullable: false,
            precision: null as any,
            createDate: true,
            comment: 'Data de Criação',
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: 'timestamp',
            default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
            nullable: false,
            precision: null as any,
            updateDate: true,
            comment: 'Data de Atualização',
            onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
        },
    },
    relations: {
        company: {
            type: 'one-to-one',
            target: 'company',
            joinColumn: {
                name: 'idCompany',
                referencedColumnName: 'idCompany',
                foreignKeyConstraintName: 'FK_Company_CompanySettings',
            },
            onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        },
        companySettingsTranslations: {
            type: 'one-to-many',
            target: 'companySettingsTranslation',
            inverseSide: 'companySettings',
        },
    },
    indices: [{ columns: ['idCompany'], name: 'FK_Company_RadarDescription' }],
    uniques: [{ columns: ['idCompany'], name: 'idCompany' }],
});
```

With that the migration creates two UNIQUE INDEX:

```
CREATE TABLE \`companySettings\` (
                \`idCompanySettings\` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Chave primária',
                \`idCompany\` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Chave da Empresa',
                \`radarCulturalImage\` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET "utf8mb4" COLLATE "utf8mb4_unicode_ci" NULL COMMENT 'Imagem customizada da empresa usada no radar' DEFAULT NULL,
                \`disableCountry\` enum ('true', 'false') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Desabilita o país' DEFAULT 'false',
                \`disablePositionLevel\` enum ('true', 'false') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Desabilita nível de cargo' DEFAULT 'false',
                \`disableSchoolLevel\` enum ('true', 'false') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Desabilita nível escolar' DEFAULT 'false',
                \`createdAt\` timestamp NOT NULL COMMENT 'Data de Criação' DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                \`updatedAt\` timestamp NOT NULL COMMENT 'Data de Atualização' DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                INDEX \`FK_Company_RadarDescription\` (\`idCompany\`),
                UNIQUE INDEX \`idCompany\` (\`idCompany\`),
                UNIQUE INDEX \`REL_d2f2efb4db98cf928a75c79447\` (\`idCompany\`),
                PRIMARY KEY (\`idCompanySettings\`)
            ) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I tried the createForeignKeyConstraints option set to true and the migration creates one UNIQUE INDEX correctly, but does not create the foreignKey, obviously. Also, i tried to search in the relation options and the entity options itself and I haven't found anything to indicate that this is possible.

What can I do?